# .htaccess rewrite for sub pages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the current rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This works wonderfully for http://www.example.com/something but I would also like to be able to have sub pages, ie: http://www.example.com/something/something. I would like it to take the form of:

`index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2`

or

`index.php?page=something&subpage=$1`

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2 [L,QSA]
```

You can also make both in one rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:([^/]+)|)(?:/([^/]+)|)/?$ index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: +1 for the 2nd **2 in 1 rule** but I prefer keep them separate. Much easier to maintain.

Comment: @anubhava same I prefer to keep rules separated for maintainability but since I was not sure of his intentions I posted both ;).